# C# - UWP open new instance of a window when middle-mouse clicking on the app's taskbar icon

Tags: c#, uwp, taskbar

Perhaps this is a silly question, however I've searched around quite a bit and not been able to find an answer related to UWP apps.

How can one trigger an instance of their app's main window to open when middle-mouse clicking the taskbar icon? Edge can do it, so I'm assuming it's possible, just not documented or frequently done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, UWP apps support only one view (window) per app at one time so when user tries to open an UWP app that is already running, system switches to the running app rather then creating a new instance.

So you have to support multiple views in your app in order to create new instance when middle-clicked on taskbar.

You can find some documentation about multiple views in UWP app on MSDN, for example in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views) article.

Comment: Sorry for the delay here, thanks for the reply! Adding support for multiple views did the trick.